# A mapping that does not preserve convergence in distribution

Tags: probability-theory, random-variables, weak-convergence

I'm trying to come up with a map $H: \mathbb{R}^k\to \mathbb{R}^k$ and a sequence of random vectors $X_n\Rightarrow X$ in $\mathbb{R}^k$ for which $H(X_n)$ does not converge in distribution to $H(X)$. Any ideas?

I want to use an example for the section I'm teaching tomorrow (I'm covering convergence).

Answer (score 0):

Convergence in distribution is preserved by continuous maps, or more generally by maps for which the measure of discontinuity points are of null measure for the limiting law.

Without this assumption, the result may fail.

If we consider the case $k=1$, then we can take a simple example: $X_n:=1/n$, $X=0$ and $H(x):=\chi_{(0,1)}(x)$, where $\chi_S$ is the characteristic function of the set $S$. We have $H(X_n)=1$ for each $n$ and $H(X)=0$.

Comment: What exactly does $\chi_{(0,1)}$ mean?

Comment: The characteristic function of this interval.